# Error in `dplyr::mutate()` when I use the code from GitHub

Tags: r, dplyr

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=14, fig.height=8, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE, cache=FALSE,
                      warning=FALSE, message=FALSE,
                      cache.lazy = FALSE)

## Load packages
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE)
library(ggrepel, quietly = TRUE)
library(knitr, quietly = TRUE)
library(here, quietly = TRUE)
library(ggplot2, quietly = TRUE)
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE)
library(ggstar, quietly = TRUE)
library(omd, quietly = TRUE)
source("01-helpers.R")
figdir = "~/Dropbox/Apps/Overleaf/OMD/figures"
```

There is no error and it shows the path of the file `here() starts at C:/Users/jerry/Desktop/Code/main`, and a

```
── Conflicts ────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

Here's the box we'll focus on.

```
lat = 19.8968
lon = -155.5828
boxsize = 40
lonrange = lon + c(-1,1) * boxsize
latrange = lat + c(-1,1) * boxsize
latrange = pmin(latrange, 48.25) 
latrange = pmax(latrange, -20.5) 
restrictbox <- . %>% filter(lat > latrange[1],
                            lat < latrange[2],
                            lon > lonrange[1],
                            lon < lonrange[2])
world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
```

### Load data

First, we load Darwin data (from https://github.com/brorfred/ocean_clustering/)
at 2-degree resolution.

```
ddat = read.csv(file.path(datadir_orig, "tabulated_darwin_montly_clim_090_180_ver_0_2_6.csv")) %>% as_tibble()
rdat = read.csv(file.path(datadir_orig, "tabulated_geospatial_montly_clim_090_180_ver_0_2_5.csv")) %>% as_tibble()
```

### Gather data

All twelve month's worth of data is first gathered into two list objects.

```
## Making common set of lon, lats.
alldat_list = alldat_list %>%
  purrr::map(. %>%
             remove_landlock() %>%
             dplyr::select(lon, lat, val) %>% 
             complete_rectangle() %>%
             dplyr::arrange(lon, lat))
```

Here it reports the error:

```
Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `land =
  mark_land(lon, lat, overreact = TRUE, buffer_in_km
  = 250)`.
Caused by error in `s2_geography_from_wkb()`:
! Evaluation error: Found 1 feature with invalid spherical geometry.
[1] Loop 120 is not valid: Edge 743 crosses edge 998.
Backtrace:
  1. alldat_list %>% ...
 29. base::stop(`<Rcpp::v_>`)
 Error in dplyr::mutate(., land = mark_land(lon, lat, overreact = TRUE, : 

Caused by error in `s2_geography_from_wkb()`:
! Evaluation error: Found 1 feature with invalid spherical geometry.
[1] Loop 120 is not valid: Edge 743 crosses edge 998.
```

How to deal with it?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting this, but typically the `.` used in dplyr pipes is used within a particular verb/function in order to refer to the piped data. For instance, in `mtcars %>% xtabs(~ cyl + gear, data = .)` the period is used to denote where the intermediate frame should be placed in the call to `xtabs`. In your call, however, you have `restrictbox <- . %>% filter(...)`, where the `.` does not make sense contextually. I recognize that that is in the source document, but I don't see how that would work. Have you reached out to the author?

Comment: @r2evans Oh, I see. But if I remove `.` in `restrictbox <- . %>% filter(...)`. It will report `Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "restrictbox <- %>%".
` No, I have not contact the author.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the `%>%` pipe and dplyr flow, that cannot work.

Comment: @r2evans I think I find the problem. I just download `tabulated_darwin_montly_clim_090_180_ver_0_2_6.csv` from GitHub and it does not include the data. So I download csv files again and make sure there is data. But there is another error..